# JavaScript - Uncaught ReferenceError: dis1 is not defined VM535:1 (anonymous function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, scope

I keep getting the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: dis1 is not defined VM535:1

(anonymous function) when I try to run the code below, however, I can't really pin-point the problem! It seems as if the function  is in scope...

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<body onclick="whatareyousingingpatrick();">
<span id="money">50</span>$
<br>
<span style="background-color:#c3c3c3;width:1000px;height:25px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;display:block;" id="track"></span>
<br>
<span id="divthing" style="position:relative;display:block;"></span>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    money = 50;
    mycars = {};

    function dodat() {
        var btn = document.createElement("div");
        btn.style.width = "25px";
        btn.style.height = "25px";
        btn.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        btn.style.boxShadow = "inset 0px 0px 0px 2px black";
        btn.style.position = "absolute";
        btn.style.left = "0px";
        btn.style.webkitTransition = "opacity 1s";
        var numba = Math.round(Math.random() * 50);
        btn.class = "haha";
        btn.id = numba;
        mycars[numba] = -50;

        var move = function () {
            mycars[numba] = mycars[numba] + 1;
            document.getElementById(numba).style.left = mycars[numba] + "px";
        };

        setInterval(move, 10);

        document.getElementById("track").appendChild(btn);
    }

    setInterval(dodat, 2000);

    function dis1() {
        $("shooter").css("background-color", "red");
        setTimeout('$("shooter").css("background-color", "blue");', '1000');
    compareEl = $("#shoot1");
        // Let's find the closest block!
        var otherEls = $('div'),
            compareTop = compareEl.offset().top,
            compareLeft = compareEl.offset().left,
            winningScore = Infinity,
            score, winner, curEl;

        otherEls.each(function () {
            // Calculate the score of this element
            curEl = $(this);
            score = Math.abs(curEl.offset().left - compareLeft);
            if (score < winningScore) {
                winningScore = score;
                winner = this;
            }
        });
        document.getElementById(winner.id).style.opacity="0";

        money = money+1;
        document.getElementById("money").innerHTML=""+money+"";
}

    function dis2() {
   compareEl2 = $("#shoot2");
        // Let's find the closest block!
        var otherEls2 = $('div'),
            compareTop2 = compareEl2.offset().top,
            compareLeft2 = compareEl2.offset().left,
            winningScore2 = Infinity,
            score2, winner2, curEl2;

        otherEls2.each(function () {
            // Calculate the score of this element
            curEl2 = $(this);
            score2 = Math.abs(curEl2.offset().left - compareLeft2);
            if (score2 < winningScore2) {
                winningScore2 = score;
                winner2 = this;
            }
        });

        document.getElementById(winner2.id).style.opacity="0";
}


    function dis3() {
   compareEl3 = $("#shoot3");
        // Let's find the closest block!
        var otherEls3 = $('div'),
            compareTop3 = compareEl3.offset().top,
            compareLeft3 = compareEl3.offset().left,
            winningScore3 = Infinity,
            score3, winner3, curEl3;

        otherEls3.each(function () {
            // Calculate the score of this element
            curEl3 = $(this);
            score3 = Math.abs(curEl3.offset().left - compareLeft3);
            if (score3 < winningScore3) {
                winningScore3 = score;
                winner3 = this;
            }
        });

        document.getElementById(winner3.id).style.opacity="0";
}


function dis4(){
   compareEl4 = $("#shoot4");
        // Let's find the closest block!
        var otherEls4 = $('div'),
            compareTop4 = compareEl4.offset().top,
            compareLeft4 = compareEl4.offset().left,
            winningScore4 = Infinity,
            score4, winner4, curEl4;

        otherEls4.each(function () {
            // Calculate the score of this element
            curEl4 = $(this);
            score4 = Math.abs(curEl4.offset().left - compareLeft4);
            if (score4 < winningScore4) {
                winningScore4 = score;
                winner4 = this;
            }
        });

        document.getElementById(winner4.id).style.opacity="0";
}
});

original = 0;
function whatareyousingingpatrick(){
if(money >= 50){
money = money-50;
original = original+1;
    setInterval("dis"+original+"();", 2500);
        var btn = document.createElement("shooter");
        btn.style.display = "block";
        btn.id = "shoot"+original+"";
        btn.style.height = "25px";
        btn.style.width = "25px";
        btn.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        btn.style.borderRadius= "100%";
        btn.style.boxShadow= "0px 0px 0px 100px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.7);";
        btn.style.position = "absolute";
        btn.style.left = event.pageX;
        btn.style.top = event.pageY;
        document.getElementById("divthing").appendChild(btn);
}
else{
alert("Sorry, this dude costs over 50 bucks.");
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `disX` functions are defined inside the `ready` callback, but `setInterval` evaluates the string in **global** scope. Either define the functions in global scope, or better, pass the function reference directly to `setInterval`.